# Javascript: How do I replace multiple same words?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I'd go about replacing multiple same words with another string.

ex.

```
"abc I abc was abc going abc to abc bed."
```

to

```
"* I * was * going * to * bed."
```

(which is an example where 'abc' would be changed to '*')

I tried `replace("abc", "*");` but I've noticed this only changes the first `abc` token that appears in the string and leaves all the others intact.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to perform a global replacement within a string.

To do so, in JavaScript, you need to:

1. Pass a Regular Expression (RegEx) as the search value (the first argument) to the `replace` method
2. Turn on the global modifier so that the RegEx is searched globally through your search string.

For your requirement:

```
var str= "abc I abc was abc going abc to abc bed.";
var newStr = str.replace(/abc/g, "*"); //newStr = "* I * was * going * to * bed."
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I chose this as the answer as I didn't even know what a regular expression was and the added explanation helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use flag "g":

```
string.replace(/abc/g, '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the /g modifier: `str.replace(/abc/g, "*")`

Comment: The code you posted is invalid.

Comment: Oops; fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var myString = "abc I abc was abc going abc to abc bed.";

var modifiedString = "";

modifiedString = myString.replace(/abc/g, '*');

alert(modifiedString);
```

Also try to this:

```
myString .replace(new RegExp("abc","g"),"*"));
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Y2R/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str= "abc I abc was abc going abc to abc bed.";

str = str.replace(/abc/g,"*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RegExp as followed:

```
    var str = "abc I abc was abc going abc to abc bed.";
    console.log(str.replace(/abc/g, "*"));
```

have a try.